# Default ScriptableObject inspector duplicates on every ListView onSelectionChange

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I'm creating some sort of database editor window, and one of the things I needed to do was show the default inspector for the currently selected scriptable object. It was a bit complicated to achieve due to the lack of documentation, but thanks to some posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977967/drawing-the-default-inspector-with-uielements-ui-builder), [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-elements-draw-default-inspector.773087/)) I got the result I wanted.

However, a great detail appeared, and that is that every time I select an SO from the list (either the same or a different one), the inspector that is displayed is duplicated.

I don't have much experience working with the UI Toolkit, I have followed some tutorials, read the existing documentation, and followed the advice of some posts. I'm still learning how to properly use it.

So, comparing my code with others, and with what I can get from the documentation, I really don't understand the reason for this behavior.

Here are the methods in charge of both creating the list and displaying the selected object:

```
private void GenerateListView() 
    {
        Func<VisualElement> makeItem = () => m_ItemRowTemplate.CloneTree();

        Action<VisualElement, int> bindItem = (e, i) =>
        {
            e.Q<Label>("Name").text = m_LevelsDatabase[i].EditorLevelTitle;
            e.Q<Label>("Goal").text = m_LevelsDatabase[i].EditorLevelGoal;
        };

        m_ItemListView = new ListView(m_LevelsDatabase, m_ItemHeight, makeItem, bindItem);
        m_ItemListView.selectionType = SelectionType.Single;
        m_ItemListView.style.height = m_LevelsDatabase.Count * m_ItemHeight;
        m_ItemsTab.Add(m_ItemListView);

        m_ItemListView.onSelectionChange += ListViewSelectionChange;
    }
```

---

```
private void ListViewSelectionChange(IEnumerable<object> selectedItems) 
    {
        m_activeItem = (LevelInfo)selectedItems.First();

        SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(m_activeItem);

        var iterator = so.GetIterator();
        if (iterator.NextVisible(true))
        {
            do
            {
                var propertyField = new PropertyField(iterator.Copy()) { name = "PropertyField:" + iterator.propertyPath };

                if (iterator.propertyPath == "m_Script" && so.targetObject != null)
                    propertyField.SetEnabled(value: false);

                m_DefaultInspector.Add(propertyField);
            }
            while (iterator.NextVisible(false));
        }

        m_DetailSection.Bind(so);

        m_DetailSection.style.visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: I see where you add fields to the `m_DefaultInspector`. Where do you remove or clear them when deselecting?

Comment: @DMGregory Ohhh I see, so, I actually figured it out moments later after I posted this. I just added `m_DefaultInspector.Clear()` at the beggining of `ListViewSelectionChange()`, but I thought that was some kind of workaround, not the actual way of doing it, so I left the question open in case there was another way to do it. But if that's the way it's done then I think it's solved.

Comment: Great. Want to write up your solution as an Answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although quite easy, it was just a matter of removing the property field from `m_DefultInspector`.

I had my suspicions that this was the problem, since sure enough, every time the `ListViewSelectionChange()` method was called, `m_DefultInspector.Add()` was also called, which made me wonder: at what point do we reset the value of `m_DefultInspector`? Having little experience using the UI Toolkit, I thought maybe there was some special method to do that.

But no, it was a matter of clearing the variable with the Clear() method before proceeding to add a property field to it.

```
void YourMethod()
{
   m_VisualContainer.Clear();
   
   // The rest of your code + m_VisualContainer.Add();
}
```